# No clue.. Overflow, Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0006'

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I'm receiving suddenly this error on a Win2003 Server Web Application:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0006'

Overflow: 'Appname'

A bunch of updates where performed on this server but I have rolled them back all.

The page is old ASP code and if i run file monitor utility it will show the BUFFER OVERFLOW when it hits a GIF.

Any ideas?

Comment: Because you are running Windows Server 2003 you may be affected by a fault in the C++ Runtime library and can download a hotfix from Microsoft. For further details, refer to Microsoft KB955536 - [VBScript throws a floating-point exception when the C runtime returns a stale floating-point status flag in a Windows Server 2003 environment](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955536).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0006'` almost always indicates a divide by zero error.

Comment: "almost" indicates "not always"

Comment: @Patonza would you prefer "<some number I made up>% of the time"?

Comment: no thanks :) There are plenty of other cases leading to Overflow in vbscript and your answer relegated them into the "almost never" zone. That doesn't sound good to me but I could be just wrong on this.

Comment: obviously, you are making fun of my remark here. But your answer is still useless in most cases, now it's just more confusing ;)

Comment: Confusing yes, but useless? No way.

Comment: @Randolpho : Almost %100 agreed with you!

Comment: @Patonza "most" indicates "not always"

Answer (score 2):

You can reproduce the `Overflow` error like this :

```
Dim testVar
testVar = 99999
testVar = CInt(testVar)
```

So, maybe this indicates there are some problems with the data types where you are setting some variables on that file?

Answer (score 1):

Can you figure out where in the file the error is happening?  You can use

Response.Write "here"
Response.End

And then load the page to see what point it gets to.  Then you can post the code that is crashing and we may be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a function with Out of Range variable 
If you used integer variable and the variable posses greater than 
integer range then its shows error.

**Explanation:**

```
Dim IntVar AS Integer
IntVar = 50000
```

Then it must show overflow error

So you can use following code instead of given code

```
Dim LongVar As Long
longVar = 50000
```