# How do I solve this? Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0006' Overflow /Variable.asp, line 27

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Here's my Code. I'm making a website that solves for a quadratic formula for my requirement. And it requires to call at least three variables from a form.

```html
<form action="Variable.asp" id="arrays" method="get">
    <label for="category">A: </label><br>
    <input name="aname" id="aname"><br>

    <label for="category">B: </label><br>
    <input name="bname" id="bname"><br>

    <label for="category">C: </label><br>
    <input name="cname" id="cname"><br>
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

```vb
<%
    Function solvex1(a,b,c)
        x1 = (b * b)
        x1 = x1 - (4 * (a * c))
        x1 = Sqr(x1)
        x1 = -b + x1
        x1 = x1 / (2 * a)
        x1 = CInt(x1)
        x1 = x1
    End Function

    Function solvex2(a,b,c)
        x2 = (b * b)
        x2 = x2 - (4 * (a * c))
        x2 = Sqr(x2)
        x2 = -b - x2
        x2 = x2 / (2 * a)
        x2 = CInt(x2)
        x2 = x2
    End Function


    Response.Write("Here is your answer: <br>")
    Response.Write("X1 = ")
    Response.Write(solvex1(Request.Form("aname"), Request.Form("bname"), Request.Form("cname")) & "<br>")
    Response.Write("X2 = ")
    Response.Write(solvex2(Request.Form("aname"), Request.Form("bname"), Request.Form("cname")) & "<br>")
%>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789663/no-clue-overflow-microsoft-vbscript-runtime-error-800a0006?rq=1 here someone had also an 800a0006 runtime error. Maybe the variable "a" is zero?

Comment: I've already seen that but it didn't help. When I also add a value to "a" still gets the error.

Comment: Before doing any mathematical calculations make sure all the variables you pass into the function are numeric, you can use a combination of `IsNumeric()` to check and `CInt()` or `CLng()` to convert them.

Comment: See this too: [Cint overflow error when value exceeds 100,000+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967448/cint-overflow-error-when-value-exceeds-100-000)

Comment: I have solved the issues but if I start it returns Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0006' Overflow because there where no Values on the variables but when I entered Values using the user input it solves the error. Don't know how to add values before user input tho.

Comment: The form method is `get`, so the `request` values have to be accessed using `Request.Querystring("fieldname")` or simply `Request("fieldname")` which will work for both `get` and `post` methods.

Comment: If you enclose all the `Response.Write`s within a check like `If Request("aname")<> "" Then` you won't get the initial errors.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is you don’t return anything from your function calls, but you expect to output their value in a `Response.Write()` call.

Try changing the function definitions to show you want to return the value. Here is the `solvex1()` function rewritten to return the value of `x1`:

```vb
Function solvex1(a,b,c)
    Dim x1
    x1 = (b * b)
    x1 = x1 - (4 * (a * c))
    x1 = Sqr(x1)
    x1 = -b + x1
    x1 = x1 / (2 * a)
    x1 = CInt(x1)
    x1 = x1
    'Return the value from the function.
    solvex1 = x1
End Function
```

To return a value from a function assign it to the name of the function.

Also, would highly recommend checking the values you pass into the function are valid numeric values **before** any mathematical calculations are performed.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Return value from a VBScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15667474/692942)
- [How to indicate if string has numeric value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11450288/692942)